# How do I pull submit value from the same page?

Tags: php, url

I have a searchbar.php file and when I hit submit I want the URL to say something like:

```
/search.php?result=<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>
```

so...I tried this:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php?result=<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

which yielded this:

```
/search.php?result=
```

I know that it's making that page before it can get ahold of the search value, but is there a way to make it so it works?

I also tried this on my search.php page:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
header('Location: search.php?result='.$search.'');
?>
```

but I got a redirect loop.  Also as a side note, what is that called when you add a ?foo=bar at the end of a URL? I never knew.

Comment: Usually when you want to process in the same page, you would use `action=""` but am not sure if this would work in your case. You could try it, you've nothing to lose.

Comment: There's probably a missing semi-colon in `<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>` could try adding one `<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>`

Comment: *"what is that called when you add a ?foo=bar"* You have to use GET and not POST to get that type of result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <form method="GET" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If you use get, it will automtically put the search string after the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change method from `post` to `get`